# How to make ImageButton always be at the bottom of the screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have created a xml design for this case.

But I got a problem when the ListView has finished reading the data and display data to the screen, but then ImageButton later covered/disappear by listView.

My code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#E6E6E6"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tanggal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#FF2300"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.costum.android.widget.LoadMoreListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:cacheColorHint="#EBEBEB"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notfound"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/notfound"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelBaru"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/netTrouble"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/txt_failed"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/LoadingData"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnImg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/coba" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I guess at the `android:layout_height="match_parent"` who make this happen. How do I fix it?

Comment: change linear to Relative and use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your image button

Comment: Give a specific height to your listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your list view is match parent so change your xml like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/content_frame"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#E6E6E6"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tanggal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="#FF2300"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<com.costum.android.widget.LoadMoreListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:cacheColorHint="#EBEBEB"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notfound"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/notfound"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/panelBaru"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/netTrouble"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txt_failed"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/LoadingData"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnImg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/coba" />
  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

by doing this your list view takes only remaining place. If any Problem Please comment.

Comment: Hai @Cropper : I have tried to give you the result is `ImageButton` show on the bottom of the screen but my listview disappears, and does not display data. Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<com.costum.android.widget.LoadMoreListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:cacheColorHint="#EBEBEB"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

to

```
<com.costum.android.widget.LoadMoreListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:cacheColorHint="#EBEBEB"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to replace com.costum.android.widget.LoadMoreListView definition

```
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

with

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

The harder way is to change layout of All view from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout.
Then You have to set 'panelBaru' alignParentBottom and with wrap_content height and listView above it

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: You can add some description as well.